# Cómo ajustar FILEUPLOAD en RichFaces cuando termine el soporte a Adobe FLash?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

En donde trabajo tenemos un sistema que utiliza RichFaces con el módulo FileUpload , como sabran Adobe Flash dejará de funcionar en los navegadores y consecuentemente el módulo de subida de archivos, saben de alguna alternativa para que siga funcionando?

les dejo el código del módulo en la parte de abajo:

```
<rich:fileUpload disabled="false" autoclear="true"
               fileUploadListener="#{importacionesController.listener}"
               maxFilesQuantity="5"
               id="upload"
               immediateUpload="true"
               acceptedTypes="csv, txt,pwd,xml" 
               allowFlash="true"
               addControlLabel="Agregar"
               clearAllControlLabel=" Limpiar todo"
               clearControlLabel="Limpiar"
               stopControlLabel="Detener proceso"
               uploadControlLabel="Subir"
               doneLabel="Agregado"
               stopEntryControlLabel="Detener">
               
               <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="info" ajaxSingle="true"/>
           </rich:fileUpload>
```

Ya intenté poner la línea  `allowFlash="false"` pero de este modo el módulo no funciona.

Espero que me puedan ayudar por favor.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido. Por favor, evita las mayúsculas sostenidas. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Sobre tu pregunta: la [documentación](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html) dice que el módulo flash incorporado añade funcionalidades, pero que sin habilitarlo también funciona. También puedes revisar si alguna de las respuestas [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240628/236345) te sirven.